# Why wont my simon game work and what do i need to do so it works

Tags: java, bluej

Im making a simon game and i have no idea what to do.  I got sound and all that good stuff working but as for everything else I have no idea what im doing.  I need some help making the buttons work and flash in the right order.  (comments are failed attempts)  Any help is very much appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game extends JFrame
{
JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
JLabel label1, label2, label3;
JPanel panel1, panel2;

File wavFile1 = new File("NewRing1.wav");
File wavFile2 = new File("NewRing2.wav");
File wavFile3 = new File("NewRing3.wav");
File wavFile4 = new File("NewRing4.wav");
AudioClip sound1;
AudioClip sound2;
AudioClip sound3;
AudioClip sound4;

int sequence1;
int[] anArray;

public Game()
{
    anArray = new int[1000];
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 2);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(grid);
    Container theContainer = this.getContentPane();
    EtchedBorder edge = new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);

    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button1.setBackground(Color.RED);

    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    button3 = new JButton();
    button3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    button4 = new JButton();
    button4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    button5 = new JButton("Begin");

    label1 = new JLabel("Score");
    label2 = new JLabel("High Score");
    label3 = new JLabel("Follow The Pattern");

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(label1);
    panel1.add(label2);

    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.add(label3);
    panel2.add(button5);

    button1.setBorder(edge);
    button2.setBorder(edge);
    button3.setBorder(edge);
    button4.setBorder(edge);
    label1.setBorder(edge);
    label2.setBorder(edge);
    panel1.setBorder(edge);
    panel2.setBorder(edge);
    label3.setBorder(edge);

    theContainer.add(panel1);
    theContainer.add(panel2);
    theContainer.add(button1);
    theContainer.add(button2);
    theContainer.add(button3);
    theContainer.add(button4);

    Button1Handler handleButton1 = new Button1Handler();
    button1.addActionListener(handleButton1);

    Button2Handler handleButton2 = new Button2Handler();
    button2.addActionListener(handleButton2);

    Button3Handler handleButton3 = new Button3Handler();
    button3.addActionListener(handleButton3);

    Button4Handler handleButton4 = new Button4Handler();
    button4.addActionListener(handleButton4);

    Button5Handler handleButton5 = new Button5Handler();
    button5.addActionListener(handleButton5);

    try{sound1 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile1.toURL());}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    try{sound2 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile2.toURL());}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    try{sound3 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile3.toURL());}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    try{sound4 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile4.toURL());}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    setVisible(true);
}

public class Button1Handler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        sound1.play();

    }
}

public class Button2Handler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        sound2.play();

    }
}

public class Button3Handler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        sound3.play();

    }
}

public class Button4Handler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        sound4.play();

    }
}
/*
public static int[] buttonClicks(int[] anArray) 
{
return anArray;
}
 */

public class Button5Handler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 159; i++)
        { 
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt(40) % 4 + 1;
            anArray[i] = randomNum;
            System.out.println("Element at index: "+ i + " Is: " + anArray[i]);
        }
        buttonClicks(anArra[3]);
        /*
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if(randomNum == 1)
        {
        button1.doClick();

        sequence1 = 1;
        System.out.println(sequence1);
        }

        else if(randomNum == 2)
        {
        button2.doClick();

        sequence1 = 2;
        System.out.println(sequence1);
        }

        else if(randomNum == 3)
        {
        button3.doClick();

        sequence1 = 3;
        System.out.println(sequence1);
        }

        else
        {
        button4.doClick();

        sequence1 = 4;
        System.out.println(sequence1);
        }

        }
         */

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you explain in more detail what is working and what is not? We would appreciate if you break down your code base to the essential parts needed. My suggestion is that nobody will read all this code to find the bugs.

Comment: Here's something you can do.  Study the [Oracle Tutorial Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  Study every page.  Take several months to study the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some code to get you started. The playback of the sequences is executed in a separate thread, as you need to use delays in between. This code is by no means ideal. You should use better names for the variables and refactor to try to create a better and more encapsulated game model. Maybe you could use this opportunity to learn about the [MVC design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    JPanel panel1, panel2;

    File wavFile1 = new File("NewRing1.wav");
    File wavFile2 = new File("NewRing2.wav");
    File wavFile3 = new File("NewRing3.wav");
    File wavFile4 = new File("NewRing4.wav");
    AudioClip sound1;
    AudioClip sound2;
    AudioClip sound3;
    AudioClip sound4;

    int level;
    int score;
    int[] anArray;
    int currentArrayPosition;

    public Game() {
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 2);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(grid);
        Container theContainer = this.getContentPane();
        EtchedBorder edge = new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);

        level = 0;
        score = 0;
        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button1.setBackground(Color.RED);

        button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        button3 = new JButton();
        button3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        button4 = new JButton();
        button4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        button5 = new JButton("Begin");

        label1 = new JLabel("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
        label2 = new JLabel("High Score");
        label3 = new JLabel("Follow The Pattern");

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(label1);
        panel1.add(label2);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(label3);
        panel2.add(button5);

        button1.setBorder(edge);
        button2.setBorder(edge);
        button3.setBorder(edge);
        button4.setBorder(edge);
        label1.setBorder(edge);
        label2.setBorder(edge);
        panel1.setBorder(edge);
        panel2.setBorder(edge);
        label3.setBorder(edge);

        theContainer.add(panel1);
        theContainer.add(panel2);
        theContainer.add(button1);
        theContainer.add(button2);
        theContainer.add(button3);
        theContainer.add(button4);

        Button1Handler handleButton1 = new Button1Handler();
        button1.addActionListener(handleButton1);

        Button2Handler handleButton2 = new Button2Handler();
        button2.addActionListener(handleButton2);

        Button3Handler handleButton3 = new Button3Handler();
        button3.addActionListener(handleButton3);

        Button4Handler handleButton4 = new Button4Handler();
        button4.addActionListener(handleButton4);

        Button5Handler handleButton5 = new Button5Handler();
        button5.addActionListener(handleButton5);

        try {
            sound1 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile1.toURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sound2 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile2.toURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sound3 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile3.toURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sound4 = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile4.toURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Button1Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            sound1.play();
            buttonClicked(button1);
        }
    }

    public class Button2Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            sound2.play();
            buttonClicked(button2);
        }
    }

    public class Button3Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            sound3.play();
            buttonClicked(button3);
        }
    }

    public class Button4Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            sound4.play();
            buttonClicked(button4);
        }
    }

    private void buttonClicked(JButton clickedButton) {
        if (isCorrectButtonClicked(clickedButton)) {
            currentArrayPosition++;
            addToScore(1);
            if (currentArrayPosition == anArray.length) {
                playNextSequence();
            } else {
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, String.format("Your scored %s points", score));
            score = 0;
            level = 0;
            label1.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
        }
    }

    private boolean isCorrectButtonClicked(JButton clickedButton) {
        int correctValue = anArray[currentArrayPosition];
        if (clickedButton.equals(button1)) {
            return correctValue == 1;
        } else if (clickedButton.equals(button2)) {
            return correctValue == 2;
        } else if (clickedButton.equals(button3)) {
            return correctValue == 3;
        } else if (clickedButton.equals(button4)) {
            return correctValue == 4;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Button5Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            playNextSequence();
        }
    }

    private void playNextSequence() {
        level++;
        currentArrayPosition = 0;
        anArray = createSequence(level);
        (new Thread(new SequenceButtonClicker())).start();
    }

    private int[] createSequence(int sequenceLength) {
        int[] sequence = new int[sequenceLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt(40) % 4 + 1;
            sequence[i] = randomNum;
        }
        return sequence;
    }

    private JButton getButtonFromInt(int sequenceNumber) {
        switch (sequenceNumber) {
            case 1:
                return button1;
            case 2:
                return button2;
            case 3:
                return button3;
            case 4:
                return button4;
            default:
                return button1;
        }
    }

    private void flashButton(JButton button) throws InterruptedException {
        Color originalColor = button.getBackground();
        button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 200));
        Thread.sleep(250);
        button.setBackground(originalColor);
    }

    private void soundButton(JButton button) {
        if (button.equals(button1)) {
            sound1.play();
        } else if (button.equals(button2)) {
            sound2.play();
        } else if (button.equals(button3)) {
            sound3.play();
        } else if (button.equals(button4)) {
            sound4.play();
        }
    }

    private void addToScore(int newPoints) {
        score += newPoints;
        label1.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
    }

    private class SequenceButtonClicker implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
                try {
                    JButton nextButton = getButtonFromInt(anArray[i]);
                    soundButton(nextButton);
                    flashButton(nextButton);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have got most of it working however when i play the game it doesn't play the previous pattern.  I only plays what is next in the array.  I would like it to start at 0 again and have the user play the whole new pattern again with one more space long.